# I use the API to share with others and return You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate?

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I use P12 password upload a file share with others but returns an error bad request. User message:

```
Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate."
```

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the file itself and not related to the api

if your file was flagged you can go to the drive web application and request that the file be reviewed again [review](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2463328?hl=en)

if the file is uploaded to the server account drive account I don't think you can request a review.

remember there are several types of files that drive probably won't let you share .zip is one

Comment: But I can't share this folder with the folder generated with the API